# Does EHCache 1.7.1 is compatible with JDK 8?

Tags: java-8, ehcache

I am using Ehcache 1.7.1 with JDK 7. Can anyone confirm that EHCache 1.7.1 works with JDK 8?

Comment: Java is backward compatible, any old libraries should be able to run on new JDK. We are on java 8 and most of the libraries we use are developed on Java 7. You would have problems when the tool that is using the EHCache needs an advanced version of the EHCache because some of the interface methods are not available etc., But, in your case you should not have any issues.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and improve your question as it currently stands to be 'Off topic' and likely to be downvoted and / or flagged & closed.

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache 1.7.1 [arrived in Maven Central in 2009](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/1.7.1/) so was clearly not tested on Java 8. So I recommend testing it yourself and be ready to upgrade if it fails to work.